# How to create a site with pagination with the same URL?

Tags: pagination

I'm trying to create a page with articles on it, on the bottom of the page I want pagination to continue the articles on different pages (but the same URL). So for example, 5 articles are showing on one page, and you have to click "2" or "next" to get to the next 5 articles and so on. When the user clicks "2" or "next", I want the URL to stay the same but have ?pg=2 at the end of it.

Maybe I'm overthinking this but I can't find a solution to this.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

The approach is ok.

When a user clicks on the 'next page' button, you redirect to `<url>?p=<next page number>`. The server would use the session parameter `p` to serve the objects for the requested page.

Pagination should be done on the backend, you don't want to send *all* pages to the client at once.